# How to refactor this simple code to avoid code duplication?

Tags: c++, code-organization

I am solving the following simple problem(on one of OnlineJugde sites which is in Russian, so I won't give a link here:). It is easier to state the problem via an example than definition.

***Input:***

```
10 // this is N, the number of the integers to follow
1 1 1 2 2 3 3 1 4 4
```

***Output:***

```
3 times 1.
2 times 2.
2 times 3.
1 times 1.
2 times 4.
```

***Constraints:***
All the numbers in the input(including **N**) are positive integer less than **10000**.

Here is the code I got ***Accepted*** with:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int n; 
   cin >> n;
   int prevNumber = -1;
   int currentCount = 0;
   int currentNumber;
   while(n --> 0)  // do n times
   {
      cin >> currentNumber;
      if(currentNumber != prevNumber)
      {
         if(currentCount != 0) //we don't print this first time
         {
            cout << currentCount << " times " << prevNumber << "." << endl;
         }
         prevNumber = currentNumber;
         currentCount = 1;
      }
      else //if(currentNumber == prevNumber)
      {
         ++currentCount;
      }
   }
   cout << currentCount << " times " << prevNumber << "." << endl;
}
```

Now here's my problem. A little voice inside me keeps telling me that I am doing this line two times:

```
cout << currentCount << " times " << prevNumber << "." << endl;
```

I told that voice inside me that it might be possible to avoid printing separately in the end. It told me that there would then be perhaps way too many `if`'s and `else`'s for such a simple problem. Now, I ***don't*** want to make the code ***shorter***. Nor do I want do minimize the number of `if`'s and `else`'s. *But I **do** want to get rid of the special printing in the end of the loop without making the code more complicated.*

I really believe this simple problem can be solved with simpler code than mine is. Hope I was clear and the question won't be deemed as not constructive :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give the link in russian

Comment: @Leon: But does that matter? Is the problem not clear enough? :)

Comment: It's fine, duplicating a couple cout's for the sake of code simplicity is the right thing to do.

Comment: problem is clear, just interested in what the site is

Comment: @Tom K: I believe it ***can*** be avoided ***without*** sacrificing simplicity. I just cannot figure out how... Or maybe it can't... I don't know, that's why I asked the question

Comment: I see you have found the famous "goes down to" operator `-->`.

Comment: @Bo Persson: It's not only fancy, it's really convenient! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i came up with this. no code duplication, but slightly less readable. Using vector just for convenience of testing

**EDIT** my answer assumes you know the numbers ahead of time and not processing them on the fly

```
vector<int> numbers;
numbers.push_back(1);
numbers.push_back(1);
numbers.push_back(1);
numbers.push_back(2);
numbers.push_back(2);
numbers.push_back(3);
numbers.push_back(3);
numbers.push_back(1);
numbers.push_back(4);
numbers.push_back(4);


for (int i=0; i<numbers.size(); i++)
{
    int count = 1;
    for (int j=i+1; j<numbers.size() && numbers[i] == numbers[j]; i++, j++)
    {
        count++;
    }
    cout << count << " times " << numbers[i] << "." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Side comment, when having to initialize a vector from a large set of values (C++03) you can use an array: `int data[] = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4 }; std::vector<int> numbers( data, data+ (sizeof data/ sizeof *data) );`

Comment: Why can't you use:
`vector<int> numbers;
int n;
cin >> n;
while(n-- > 0) { int x; cin >> x; numbers.push_back(x); }`

Comment: depends on the question. if they want output ASAP then you cant

Comment: @user807566: A similar side comment: `std::vector<int> v; int n; std::cin >> n; std::copy_n( std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), n, std::back_inserter(v) );`

Comment: @David: Except that ***unfortunately*** `copy_n` isn't a standard function

Answer (score 2):

My version: reading the first value as a special case instead.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    int value;
    std::cin >> value;
    --n;

    while (n >= 0) {
        int count = 1;
        int previous = value;
        while (n --> 0 && std::cin >> value && value == previous) {
            ++count;
        }
        std::cout << count << " times " << previous << ".\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your loop one longer (>= 0 instead of > 0), and in the last round, instead of reading currentNumber from cin, do currentNumber = lastNumber + 1 (so that it's guaranteed to differ).

Answer (score 0):

slightly more **CREATIVE** answer, this one does not make assumption about input being all known before the start of the loop. This prints the total every time, but makes use of \r carriage return but not line feed. A new line is inserted when a different number is detected.

```
int prev_number = -1;
int current_number;
int count = 0;
for (int i=0; i<numbers.size(); i++)
{
    current_number = numbers[i];
    if (current_number != prev_number)
    {
        count = 0;
        cout << endl;
    }
    count++;
    prev_number = current_number;
    cout << count  << " times " << numbers[i] << "." << "\r";
}
```

only problem is that the cursor is left on the last line.  you may need to append `cout << endl;`

Comment: These kinds of contests require the output to match the description exactly.

Comment: and this code matches the output description directly. it makes use of carriage return to overwrite the previous line.

Comment: If output is redirected, it might not be the same. One might check whether the site accepts this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int n; 
   cin >> n;
   int prevNumber = -1;
   int currentCount = 0;
   int currentNumber;

   int i = 0;
   while(i <= n)
   {
      if(i != n) cin >> currentNumber;

      if(currentNumber != prevNumber || i == n)
      {
         if(currentCount != 0)
         {
            cout << currentCount << " times " << prevNumber << "." << endl;
         }

         prevNumber = currentNumber;
         currentCount = 1;
      }
      else
      {
         ++currentCount;
      }   
      i++;
   }
}
```

I would use a `for` loop, but I wanted to stay as close to the original as possible.